# Case ... when to create column based on other column values

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns in a table. Variable - a,b,c,d, ..... and its respective Values - 1,2,3,4, .....

Now I create a third columns using case statements

```
Case 
    When Variable IN ( a,b ) Then 'Alpha'
    When Variable IN ( c,d,e,f ) Then 'Beta'
    When Variable IN (g,h,i) Then 'Gamma' 
'As Attribute
```

This means, when I provide a Variable having its respective Value as above, I get the resultant Attribute.

Now, can I create another table where I input an Attribute and return the minimum or maximum value based on the Variable?

For Eg: If I input Beta, then the Minimum Value will be 3 (Value of Valiable 'c' since c,d,e,f have attribute Beta. In simple words reverse of the above example.

I am sure these is a simple way of doing this. Would love to see the creativity of experts here.

```
Case
    When Variable IN ( a,b ) Then 'Alpha'
    When Variable IN ( c,d,e,f ) Then 'Beta'
    When Variable IN (g,h,i) Then 'Gamma' 
'As Attribute
```

Comment: Please post an attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the `min()` calculation and then join back to the original table:

```
SELECT a.variable, b.attribute
  FROM mytable a, (SELECT min(values) as v, attribute FROM mytable GROUP BY attribute) b 
 WHERE a.values = b.v;
 variable | attribute 
----------+-----------
 a        | Alpha
 c        | Beta
 g        | Gamma
(3 rows)
```